# LED light or Indirect Sunlight for Hawaiin Tree Fern?

Tags: sunlight, ferns, led

How should I best grow a Hawaiin tree fern in my New York City apartment? I have LED lights that are currently helping my Thai and Genoa Basil plants grow. Should I also put the Hawaiin tree fern under the LED lights? Would the fern be fine on the window sill, which mainly gets indirect sunlight (maybe at most 5 hours of direct sunlight during the summer)?

My apartment does not get a lot of direct sunlight (hence the LED lights for my basil plants).

Also worth mentioning I just repotted my fern after a suspected case of root rot. It appears we were either overwatering the Hawaiin tree fern or the pot was not draining adequately.

Comment: I've recently seen some LED strips that put out near halogen lamp level light, but many of those still sold are still far too dim.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I bought these LED lights and love them, https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01M2D5SGI/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 -- my Basil and Mint plants are flourishing with them. However as you can see at the time of sharing this link the LED lights are out of stock.

Comment: @ robskrob The ones I saw were long strips whitish and painful to look at. Don't remember brand. The LED scene is changing quickly these past few years. For gardens you want 1K to 3K lumens per square foot, but wavelength matters too. Have a look at PAR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetically_active_radiation Plants will survive at less than these values, but growth will be slower.